# Manipular resultado de countBy Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy recibiendo este resultado de una consulta con countBy,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pense que podia manipularla como un Json o un Arreglo, sin embargo no logro obtener lo que quiero.

Ademas que al enviar toda la inforamcion a un .blade.php los acentos dejan de funcionar.

¿Alguna idea.?

mi consulta:

```
$query=
malformacion_paciente::whereIn
('malformacion_pacientes.nombremalformacion_id', $request->mff)
      ->LEFTJOIN('mal_formaciones AS mf', 
      'malformacion_pacientes.nombremalformacion_id', '=', 'mf.id_nombremalformacion')
      ->LEFTJOIN('formaciones AS f', 
      'f.id', '=', 'mf.formacione_id')
      ->LEFTJOIN('nombremalformacions AS nm', 
      'nm.id', '=', 'mf.id_nombremalformacion')
      ->get();

      $enfermedades = $query->countBy(function ($item) {
        return $item['descripcion'];
      });

      dd($enfermedades);
```

Busco es obtener lo que esta entre las comillas para rellenar un pdf

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
"MFC" => 7
"MSNC" => 7
"MFR" => 2
"MFME" => 1
"MFSR" => 2
```

Lo que esta entre comillas va para una tabla y los numeros para otra tabla.

Sim embargo solo me retonar los numeros, tambien requiero las palabras que estan entre comillas

Comment: Me devuelve error ErrorException
Trying to get property 'formacionName' of non-object

Comment: Vale, agregue algo a mi pregunta. Lo que requiero retornar es lo que esta enre comillas y despues de ella.

Comment: asi mismo es, usar los keys. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Como la consulta te devuelve una [Colección Elequent](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-collections), por lo que puedes usar cualquiera de los métodos disponibles para colecciones eloquent y los que hereda de la clase de [colección base](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#available-methods).

Por ejemplo:

```php
// todas las keys, o lo que tu llamas "lo que está entre comillas"
$keys = $enfermedades->keys();

// todas los values, o lo que tu llamas "los números"
$values = $enfermedades->values();

// o un simple foreach
foreach ($enfermedades as $key => $value) {
    echo "Lo que está entre comillas es {$key}";
    echo "El número es {$value}";
}
```